# How to Load Config Properties at once using python without passing section Name

Tags: python, automation, python-3.8

This is my Method :

```
def readConfigProperties(sectionName):
    # Using Confir Parser : Import the package First : add interpreter too
    config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('Path To Properties ')
    details_dict = dict(config.items(sectionName))
    print(details_dict)
    return details_dict
```

Currently i am passing Section Name and this works fine  , but i want to load full properties file in before scenario all at once .

Comment: You are loading it all. What problem are you having, it’s not clear. Are you having difficulty understanding the documentation?

Comment: i don't want to pass section name like in my code i have passed section name  , instead want contents of config properties in a dictionary without section names.

Comment: Different sections can have the same property names. Python can’t know how you want to handle name collisions. Just return the whole config object.

Comment: Like when i do it in Java , whole config properties comes as Key value pair without any sections or nested maps.

Comment: This isn’t Java

Comment: i know it is not java , but i am trying to do same thing in python , because i find it easy to use .

Comment: Don’t use ConfigFile then, as it’s a different format

Answer (score 0):

How about doing:

```
all = {} 
for section_name in config.sections():
    for name, value in config.items(section_name):
        all[name] =value
```

Answer (score 0):

`config.sections()` will return a list of sections, so for example if you wanted to read the entire config file into nested dictionaries, you could use:

```
{name: dict(config.items(name)) for name in config.sections()}
```

Example -- from input file:

```
[blah]
foo = bar

[baz]
quux = whatever
```

this would give you:

```
{'blah': {'foo': 'bar'}, 'baz': {'quux': 'whatever'}}
```